# What is the point of everyone being connected to an ISP?

Tags: internet, isp

I've heard that the Internet exchanges packets by packet switching. But why does everyone need an ISP? Can't your router just be directly connected to your neighbour's routers and their routers connected to their neighbours, all doing the packet switching? In that case, only a few would people would need to be connected to some hub or backbone which would be the gateway to the Internet outside of the neighbourhood. So why does everyone in the apartement individually connect to the ISP?

Comment: What happens in the event one router stops working and the neighbour is off on holiday for a month and can't be contacted... What happens if someone's router doesn't have the ability or capacity to log websites that are accessed and there's a dispute that someone has accessed indecent or illegal material but there's no proof so the end ISP terminates the account and everyone loses out... etc etc.

Comment: I don't know about you but I don't want to go through my neighbors router...

Answer (score 4):

> Can't your router just be directly connected to your neighbour's routers
>   and their routers connected to their neighbours, all doing the packet 
>   switching

Yes, that could work, but it does not scale.

Supposed you connect to my router. My device now has to route both my own data and your data. And if your other neighbour is connected to you can thus indirectly to me I am now routing for 3 people.  Extend for the whole street and my cheap home router might get stressed. Extend it some more and things break down. You would need much more capable devices in each home.  Technically possible, but economically not sensible,

Then there is an issue is stability. If I go on holliday then I turn off lights, computers and enything which I can. That includes my router. Hopefully both your neighbours do not go on vacation in the same period.

Finally, if something goes wrong, then you now no longer have one ISP which is serving many people and who can afford technically skilled people. You now want to train everybody. Once more: possible but economically senseless.

I can probably come up with a few more reasons if I think about this. But the three stated above are already enough to make this inefficient on a large scale with current technology.

Answer (score 3):

Well the internet is not as simple as you put it and there are many economic, security, infrastructur and technological factors to consider. I'll give you a brief and incomplete list.

1. availability and robustness: What consumer grade hardware is much more prone to failure, there is no guarantee for a fail over. What if someone just pulls the plug while you are downloading data? Of course there are alternate path, but they must be found and the whole network would be constantly be reorganising.
2. Congestion Control: You would have a large mesh of small, weak links. Congestion control already is a very hard problem as it is.
3. Addressing: IPv4 has a limited address space, so addresses must be managed hierarchically. Who does that?
4. DNS: Who would want to do that? Doing this in a hierarchical order is very easy. Imagen you would want to find out who what the persons name that on an address on the other end of the world. Just by asking your neighbours. Or the reverse
5. Actual routing: routing is bassically a giant network of computers that act like post offices. They collect traffic and send it on in the general direction it is supposed to go, while things like congestion, latency ect. in mind. Same analogy as with finding out the address.
6. Infrastructure: Someone has to build and maintain "the rest of the internet" Someone has to lay cables, build antennas etc. and solve the problems above.

Then you add a little economics to this nice mix and what you get is an ISP. Also imagine you would have to trust EVERY SINGLE PERSON in this network.

What you described is done in large corporate network, but only to a degree. Almost all of them eventually have to connect to an ISP

Answer (score 2):

**Q: But why does everyone need an ISP?**

*A: ISP is responsible for maintaining network devices, provide fault-tolerance, and fix devices ASAP in case of failure*.

**Q: Can't your router just be directly connected to your neighbor's routers and their routers connected to their neighbors, all doing the packet switching?**

*A: This would be similar to a "Mesh" or "Token Passing" topology. Then what if a device of the neighbor connected to Internet backbone fails?*

**Q: In that case, only a few would people would need to be connected to some hub or backbone which would be the gateway to the Internet outside of the neighborhood.**

*A: ISP is that "backbone which would be the gateway to the Internet outside", so why to connect to all the neighbor devices when you can reach the ISP itself?*

Devices with enough throughput for an area or neighborhood are expensive, so all the neighbors should buy one, which is far more than what ISP spends on devices!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could indeed buy your own routing gear, but that is not your only consideration.

You need infrastructure, a simplified ADSL version would look like this:

```
HouseRouter <=> Modem <=> Copper cable <=> Telco CO <=> DSLAM <=> Internet
```

Some terminology:
Telco

- CO = Central office, a box at the end of your street/a building the equipment is stored in.
- Digital subscriber line Access multiplexer, splits phone signal from your data.

Here's the fun fact, you all technically share the same route back to the ISP.
Your connection goes to the CO, and then is sent down the line until it reaches a data center. That link may be copper or it may be fiber. Eventually it hits a datacent